# Flex Populating Tree Control From DataSet

Tags: .net, apache-flex, dataset, tree

Am currently working on a Tree control, and being my first time to delve into this, I need your inputs and advice.

My tree control is retrieving data from a .NET web service.  My .NET webservice returns a string which is parsed from a dataset via the command DataSet.GetXML method.

```
Function MyFunc() as String
  'Populate the dataset here
  '.......
  Return DataSet.GetXML()
End Function
```

In my flex application, I am converting the string value returned by the webservice into an XML:

```
private var _xmlMyData:XML;

private function myResultHandler(event:ResultEvent) :void
{
  _xmlMyData = XML(event.result);
  // This script to view the XML data in Text Area
  var strData:String = String(event.result);
  taData.text = strData;
}
```

Which I am then passing to my xmlListCollection control

```
<mx:XMLListCollection id="xmllc_myData" source="{_xmlMyData.Table}" />
<mx:TextArea id="taData" width="300" height="100" />
```

Then binding to my tree control:

```
<mx:Tree id="treeOffshore" dataProvider="{xmllc_myData}" labelField="DESCN" showRoot="false">
</mx:Tree>
```

When viewing the data in the text area control, I have the following:

```
<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <CODE>A1</CODE>
    <DESC>Area One</DESC>
  </Table>

  <Table>    
    <CODE>B2</CODE>
    <DESC>Base Two</DESC>
  </Table>

  <Table>
    <CODE>C4</CODE>
    <DESC>Class Four</DESC>
  </Table>

  <Table>
    <CODE>D8</CODE>
    <DESC>Demo Eight</DESC>
  </Table>
</NewDataSet>
```

This is how the treeview renders:

```
Area One
  A1
  Area One
Base Two
  B2
  Base Two
Class Four
  C4
  Class Four
Demo Eight
  D8
  Demo Eight
```

What I want is to be able to define the Description only at the first level only:

```
Area One
Base Two
Class Four
Demo Eight
```

The next thing that I need to accomplish is that the second level of the treeview should actually be populated based on the CODE from the first level.

For example:

```
Area One
  Sub Item Area One
  Sub Item Area Two
Base Two
  Sub Item Base Two
  Sub Item Base Three
  Sub Item Base Four
Class Four
  Sub Item Class Four
Demo Eight
  Sub Item Demo Eight
  Sub Item Demo Nine
  Sub Item Demo Ten
  Sub Item Demo Eleven
```

I am quite new in this tree control thing (as well as flex) and have limited grasp of the concepts to be able to accomplish this.

I am thinking either of modifying the XML data which I originally retrieve and probably insert the sub items per each node, although I am in a bind of how to accomplish the same.

On the other hand, to give some of you further details, the treeview data would actually be coming from three tables where the table 1 is the base table, and the table 2 contains the children of table 1 and table 3 contains children data from table 3.

I would sincerely appreciate your inputs on this.  I am foraying into the world of Flex and this is quite a make or break scenario towards embracing this technology in our organization.

Thanks and hoping to get some good advice on how to accomplish this.

Regards,

Comment: I don't know anything about flex but I had a similar problem in the past with the asp.net treeview control. 
The problem was just that I didn't set a property (I don't remember the name) named ShowRoot or similar.
I recommend to just modify your binding and not the original behavior of your app.
Regards

Comment: I did toggle the showRoot property for the Tree control but still to no avail.  Thanks for the comment.